# to avoid placeholder text of textbox from storing in db as value

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

1. I applied "placeholder" attribute to my textbox.Its an optional
   field.
2. When, i used to leave this field empty,and then submit the form,its placeholder text is saved as value in the db.
3. `<input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="inktext inklarge"   placeholder="Company (Optional)"  maxlength="100" value="" />`
4. How to get rid of it.Please help.

Comment: I'm sure that isn't supposed to happen... are you sure you aren't setting the value somewhere in JavaScript?

Comment: Please show us the entire form and any scripting.

Comment: no.i am using this placeholder value in textbox only.

Comment: Its too long.ok i will try to give u.

Comment: no js i am using in this page

Answer (score 2):

It can mean either:

1. JS inserts placeholder into value
2. PHP inserts "default" value into empty field "company" before saving in DB
3. DB inserts "default" value

To check these suggestions you should:

1. var_dump($_POST) in your php file, to check if JS inserts the value before form submit
2. var_dump values you are going to insert into DB to check if php inserts default value.
3. if non of above check DB default value for that field, it should be there.